# Lua: What is an efficient square packing algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, lua

This is a generic box-packing algorithm question which I hope is alright. I'm looking into it for a 2D collision checking system in Lua, the question is as valid for other languages and use cases. I may go with a simple method such as a fixed grid if there's no easy solution to this.

I have a square describing an area defined by two start and two end coordinates, `[start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y]` so for example `[-128, 128, -256, 256]` for an 128 x 128 sized box. I have a list of several smaller squares of various sizes, one could be 16 x 16 another 48 x 48 and so on... this list is shuffled so they get iterated in a random order every time. What I want is to loop through every item in this list and add its square at a random position inside the area, adding each in a valid position where it doesn't collide with any previous item box if there's any room left.

This is difficult to solve effectively as I don't know of an efficient way to detect the empty spaces left. Best I could come up with is setting a number of chances, for each item you try a random position inside the area for # tries then give up if you collided in all of them... of course this is inefficient and wasteful on performance. Can anyone think of a smarter and more effective way to detect empty space from the squares of previous items and know where a current item of a given size would still fit? Note that I want positions randomized if possible, the goal is to allow occasional spaces as well as hide virtual areas which having everything gravitate toward the top-left corner every time may further give away.

Comment: It's not trivial, but a [sweep line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm) can be used to identify rectangular areas that aren't occupied. The general idea is that the existing boxes are represented as events: a start event `start_x, start_y, end_y` and an end event `end_x, start_y, end_y`. Create a list of events, and sort it by the `x` value. Then scan the list of events. For each start event, mark the corresponding `y` values as forbidden. For each end event, mark the corresponding `y` values as available. There's more to it, but I don't have time to write an answer.